# how can I let first value to key an second value to value in the new dictionary？

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

There are two dictionaries

```
dic_01 = {"name":"aaa","age":29}
dic_02 = {"name":"bbb","age":19}
```

I want to make a new dictionary like this

```
dic_03 = {"aaa": 29, "bbb": 19}
```

How can I do that?

I tried to solve the problem in this way

```
import pandas as pd

dic_01 = {"name":"aaa","age":29}
dic_02 = {"name":"bbb","age":19}
df = pd.DataFrame([dic_01,dic_02])
dic_03 = {}
for i in range(len(df.index)):
  dic_03[df.loc[i,"name"]] = df.loc[i,"age"]
print(dic_03)
```

Because I have more than two dictionaries to merge into one dictionary, I want to know the better way to solve the question

Comment: What exactly is difficult about the problem? What do you imagine are the logical steps required to solve the problem, and where do you get stuck when you try to write the code?

Comment: Thank you, I have added my original approach

Comment: `dict_03 = {dct["name"]: dct["age"] for dct in (dct_01, dct_02)}` but you should really have a list of those dictionaries instead of a bunch of variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# Add key to dic 3
dic_03[dic_01["name"]] = dic_01["age"]
dic_03[dic_02["name"]] = dic_02["age"]
```

For more than one dictionary. Add all to a list.

```
dic_01 = {"name":"aaa","age":29}
dic_02 = {"name":"bbb","age":19}

dics = [dic_01,dic_02]

dic_3 = {}
for dic in dics:
    dic_3[dic["name"]] = dic["age"]

print(dic_3)
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you, because I have more than two dictionaries to merge into one dictionary, I want to know the better way to solve the question

Answer (score 1):

Does it solve your problem?

```
dict1 = {"name": "aaa",
    "age": 29
    }
dict2 = {
    "name": "bbb",
    "age": 19
    }
dict3 = {
    dict1["name"]: dict1["age"],
    dict2["name"]: dict2["age"]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, because I have more than two dictionaries to merge into one dictionary, I want to know the better way to solve the question

Comment: @tientoen Have not seen your comment. As I see you got the answer, so good luck!